# Composition of morphisms of functors that is representable

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $\cal{C}$ be a category. Let $F,G,H:\cal{C}^{opp}\rightarrow Sets$ be functors. Let $f:F\rightarrow G,g:G\rightarrow H$ be morphisms of functors. Assume that the composition $g\circ f:F\rightarrow H$ is representable, i.e. for any $U\in{\rm{Ob}}(\cal{C})$, the functor $h_{U}\times_{H}F\simeq h_{W}$ for some $W\in{\rm{Ob}}(\cal{C})$. Then if $f$ is representable, can we show that $g$ is representable?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139123/discussion-on-question-by-toney-leung-composition-of-morphisms-of-functors-that).

Answer (score -1):

Here is my attempt. Suppose that $\cal{C}$ admits fibre products. Let $U,V\in{\rm{Ob}}(\cal{C})$. Take the fibre product $(h_{U}\times_{G}F)\times_{h_{U}}(h_{V}\times_{H}G)\simeq h_{V}\times_{H}F$. Since $F\rightarrow G$ is representable, choose $h_{W}\simeq h_{U}\times_{G}F$ for some $W\in{\rm{Ob}}(\cal{C})$. Then we have $h_{W\times_{U}V}\times_{H}G\simeq h_{V}\times_{H}F$.

As $V$ is arbitrary, one may choose $V$ to be $V\times_{W}U=V'$ such that $h_{V}\times_{H}G\simeq h_{V'}\times_{H}F\simeq h_{L}$ for some $L\in{\rm{Ob}}(\cal{C})$. This proves the representability of $G\rightarrow H$.